# Laravel Schedule Only Exceute Command on first Run

Tags: laravel

I create a schedule to send email everyday, but for testing if it works i make it run every minute.
here is my kernel.php

```
    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\SendExpiredReminder::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
        $schedule->command('reminder:send')
        ->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

it run every minute but reminder:send only called first time i run the schedule with `php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
when i run `php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:list` it show that next due is next minute indicated the scheduler is running. What is going wrong?

Comment: `/var/ww/html` is the root directory for laravel project?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: what is the permission of `/var/www/html` directory?

Comment: the permisiions is 777

Comment: `artisan schedule:run` should run every minute. For that you need to add a [cron configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler).

Comment: Also, definitely don't have permissions of 777. You should correctly configure groups on your server instead.

Comment: here is my etc\crontab
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
* * * * * cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: @Joundill what is the correct configuration?

Answer (score 0):

your crontab should be to your `laravel project` folder, not `www` folder

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/artisan && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

note the project folder